Ubuntu installation failing
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS in VirtualBox 7.0.18 in a Windows 10 host. But the installation is always failing.

Last messages of log:

Memory: 3129 MB
1 processor
PAE/NX enabled
Video Memory: 128 MB
Graphics controller: VBoxSVGA
Disk space: 2 TB

I suggest to use 22.04.
